# How to I correctly attribute channels from the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are trying to attribute user actions that happen after a user has signed in to the marketing channel they originated from. To do this, we use the standard Google Analytics JS library as well as the Measurement Protocol. Events get tracked in Google Analytics and they are visible in the events view. However, they do not get attributed to the correct campaign and only show up under the Direct channel.

Our process is as follows:

The user gets tracked with front end Google Analytics JS on our site:

```
ga('create', ‘UA-XXXXX-Y’, 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

A userId gets assigned to the user in Google Analytics as soon as they sign up:

```
ga('create', ‘UA-XXXXX-Y’, 'auto');
ga('set', 'userId', 'fe8220b3');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Once a certain action we would like to track happens, we send a GET request to the Measurement Protocol with the following params:

```
v: 1,
t: 'event',
tid: ‘UA-XXXXX-Y’,
cid: ‘555’,
uid: ‘fe8220b3’,
ec: ‘backend_action’,
ea: ‘action’
```

This correctly tracks the event, but does not associate it with the user. As far as I understand, since we have provided the same UserId in our params that we did when identifying the user, the attribution should happen automatically in Google Analytics. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: What happens if you make that a POST request instead? You can use the validation server here to validate your requests (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)

Comment: The events get tracked - I can see them in real time view when firing them off manually. They just don't seem to get associated with the correct user.

Comment: From my read, cid should be a random string that identifies a user and uid should a unique string that identifies the user, what that means is beyond me.

Comment: Is user id enabled in the property and session unification enabled (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780?hl=en) ? Sending the id with the code is not enough.

Comment: @EikePierstorff yup, both UserID and session unification is enabled, and I have a view using the two.